# Routes with multiple, optional, and pretty parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a situation where I'm in need to constructing pretty url paths.

I have a FilesController that need to handle URLs like:

```
mydomain.com/files/path/dir1/dir2/user/bob
mydomain.com/files/path/dir1/user/bob
mydomain.com/files/path/dir1
mydomain.com/files/user/bob
```

In the controller, I want `params[:path]` to contain everything between `/path` and `/user` and `params[:user]` to contain anything after `/user` (assuming only one user and it's optional).

I'm looking for the best way to do this, preferable with just one statement in the `routes.rb` file. The trickiest part, I think, is that after `/path` an actual path to a file might be provided, N times deep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [route globbing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments):

```
match 'files/*path/user/:user' => 'user#files'
```

You might also need to add an additional route for the case where there is no path:

```
match 'files/user/:user' => 'user#files'
```

Comment: I think I would still need another route to cover the `mydomain.com/files/path/dir1` case.

Comment: The anchor on Chris' link has changed: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Chris Heald's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14007710/373522), I ended up going with this, which fit the scenario:

```
match 'files/user/:user' => 'files#index'
match 'files/path/*path/user/:user' => 'files#index'
match 'files/path/*path' => 'files#index'
```

Still wondering if this could've been handled with a one-liner.

Comment: You could use `files/path/*path` and then just try to suck a username off the end of `params[:path]` if you really want the one-liner.

Comment: Any update to this?  I'm facing the same problem and don't want to have multiple routes for the same thing, like the above stated scenario.